# Viewing current frequency on Kenwood TM-281

Tags: kenwood

Once you program a memory name on this radio, it displays the name only. Is there any way to quickly confirm the actual frequency of a named memory?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it can be done quickly, but you can change the settings to display the freq instead of the memory name. From page 32 of the [manual](http://manual.kenwood.com/files/4ee059ba1d903.pdf) ([available from the Kenwood website](http://manual.kenwood.com/en_contents/search)):

> To display the frequency rather than Memory Name, access Menu No. 17 (MDF) and select “FRQ”.  This menu toggles the display mode between the Memory Name (“MN”) and frequency display (“FRQ”).

Answer (score 0):

I guess <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>VFO</kbd> would do it since that copies the memory to the VFO, and the name doesn't appear in VFO mode. Given the small number of buttons on this radio, there's probably not a better way to do it.